# Subsetting long data frame in R based on matching variables

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have created a long data frame in R. When converting from a wide data frame to a long data frame, a number of rows were matched that are incorrect.

Specifically, there are two columns that I need to match based on a scheme. For example, the current data frame looks something like this:

```r
Variable1 Variable2
T1 T1.T2
T2 T1.T2
T3 T1.T2
T1 T1.T3
T2 T1.T3
T3 T1.T3
```

I want to keep the rows where <Variable 1, T1> equals <Variable 2, T1.T2> and <Variable 1, T2> equals <Variable 2, T1.T3>, etc.

Is this possible? How would I implement this? I can do it manually but I would prefer if there is an easier option :)

Thank you! Please respond if you need any further information.

Comment: If your previous step "matched" too many rows when converting to a long format, I suggest you should fix that step instead of trying to patch mistakes from it. Otherwise, have you tried good-ole `subset`? This produces two rows: `subset(dat, (Variable1 == "T1" & Variable2 == "T1.T2") | (Variable1 == "T2" & Variable2 == "T1.T3"))`.

Comment: @r2evans "subset" did the trick, thank you! That is perfect. I haven't used R in a few years so thanks for helping me get back into the swing of it! :)